# Какую архитектуру кода выбрать для написания IDE?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ide

Хочу портировать IDEA на Android. Уже написал "IDE" в которой можно редактировать пока только один Main.java, компилировать, запускать его и выводить результат выполнения. Подсветки синтаксиса, автоформата, автодополнения, реалтайм-ошибок нету. Лишь голый интерфейс а-ля блокнот. Куда копать  чтобы сделать все, что есть в IDEA?  Какую архитектуру кода выбрать? Как и где хранить переменные, классы и т.д?

Comment: копайте в сторону eclipse platform или netbeans platform

Comment: У IDEA community edition открытый исходный код, можете посмотреть как там сделано https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community

Comment: @Vadik  я бы оформил это как ответ, исходя из текущего вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код IDEA community edition открыт, предлагаю ознакомиться и подглядеть, как сделано там https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community